# Troubles processing data from Async calls

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

So this is my task:

> You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the
>   URLs an d print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print
>   out the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch
>   is that you must prin t them out in the same order as the URLs are
>   provided to you as command-line  arguments.

And I'm doing it like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var dataStream = [];
var dataArr = [];
var count = 0;
/*
 Function to print results
 @dataArr - array
*/
function printResults(dataArr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < process.argv.length - 2; i++)
    console.log(dataArr[i]);
}

/*
  Function to get data from http
  @i - int
  Getting command line arguments as parametrs.
*/
function httpGet(i) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + i], function(res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(data) {
      dataStream.push(data);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      dataArr[i] = (dataStream.join(""));
      dataStream = [];
      count++;
      if (count == process.argv.length - 2) {
        printResults(dataArr);
      }
    });

    res.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < process.argv.length - 2; i++) {
  httpGet(i);
}
```

And for some reason sometimes it stores data in array as it supposed, but sometimes it breaks and outputs complete nonsense.

Some results examples:

**When working**:

```
$ learnyounode verify program.js

Your submission results compared to the expected:

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────

1.  ACTUAL:    "Shazza got us some trackies when as stands out like dog's ba
lls. Grab us a show pony heaps he hasn't got a lurk. She'll be right rubbish
 mate it'll be budgie smugglers. You little ripper bloke heaps we're going t
op end. He's got a massive bog standard also built like a freckle. "
1.  EXPECTED:  "Shazza got us some trackies when as stands out like dog's ba
lls. Grab us a show pony heaps he hasn't got a lurk. She'll be right rubbish
 mate it'll be budgie smugglers. You little ripper bloke heaps we're going t
op end. He's got a massive bog standard also built like a freckle. "

2.  ACTUAL:    "As dry as a sook and as dry as a cleanskin. As cunning as a
metho where get a dog up ya parma. "
2.  EXPECTED:  "As dry as a sook and as dry as a cleanskin. As cunning as a
metho where get a dog up ya parma. "

3.  ACTUAL:    "Gutful of gyno how come a mokkies. It'll be clacker and buil
t like a holy dooley!. Get a dog up ya boozer heaps come a captain cook. "
3.  EXPECTED:  "Gutful of gyno how come a mokkies. It'll be clacker and buil
t like a holy dooley!. Get a dog up ya boozer heaps come a captain cook. "

4.  ACTUAL:    ""
4.  EXPECTED:  ""
```

**And an example when it's not working:**

```
$ learnyounode verify program.js

Your submission results compared to the expected:

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────

1.  ACTUAL:    "of bogan with it'll be rort. He hasn't got a give it a burl
flamin you little ripper dinky-di. Watch out for the mate's rate to shazza g
ot us some swag. "
1.  EXPECTED:  "He's got a massive op shop to you little ripper corker. Gutf
ul of bogan with it'll be rort. He hasn't got a give it a burl flamin you li
ttle ripper dinky-di. Watch out for the mate's rate to shazza got us some sw
ag. "

2.  ACTUAL:    "You little ripper thongs when as stands out like ropeable. T
rent from punchy boardies bloody as cunning as a brisvegas. "
2.  EXPECTED:  "You little ripper thongs when as stands out like ropeable. T
rent from punchy boardies bloody as cunning as a brisvegas. "

3.  ACTUAL:    "As dry as a uluru when come a scratchy. Flat out like a ute
with get a dog up ya chrissie. As busy as a fair go no worries it'll be fair
 dinkum. She'll be right freo when it'll be cracker. He's Watch got out a fo
r massive the op crook shop my to as you busy little as ripper a corker. bru
mby. Gutful "
3.  EXPECTED:  "As dry as a uluru when come a scratchy. Flat out like a ute
with get a dog up ya chrissie. As busy as a fair go no worries it'll be fair
 dinkum. She'll be right freo when it'll be cracker. Watch out for the crook
 my as busy as a brumby. "

4.  ACTUAL:    ""
4.  EXPECTED:  ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was:

> Your code makes the assumption that the 3 http responses will not
>   overlap - that a data event for one response will never occur before
>   the end event of the previous response, this is not always the case. I
>   recommend you move the definition of your dataStream variable inside
>   your httpGet function, this way each request/response will have its
>   own variable and they cannot interfere with each other, regardless of
>   timing.

So I refactored my solution to look like this, and now it works 100% of the time:

```
var http = require('http');
var dataArr = [];
var count = 0;
/*
 Function to print results
 @dataArr - array
*/
function printResults(dataArr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < process.argv.length - 2; i++) {
    console.log(dataArr[i].replace('undefined', ''));
  }
}

/*
  Function to get data from http
  @i - int
  Getting command line arguments as parametrs.
*/
function httpGet(i) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + i], function(res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(data) {
        dataArr[i] += data;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      count++;
      if (count == process.argv.length - 2) {
        printResults(dataArr);
      }
    });

    res.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < process.argv.length - 2; i++) {
  httpGet(i);
}
```

More info: https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/1270

Answer (score 1):

Don't treat the data you receive on res.on("data") as an array. Instead, treat it as a string and define it  as a variable within the http function (not as a global variable) and do `str += data`.

Alternatively, you could look at using a library like Async to manage the correct ordering of the async functions you need to execute, as you need each Async to be executed and returned in sequential order.

Comment: I'm getting same results, sometimes it's working, sometimes it doesn't. I know that there are some libraries to manage Async calls, but I didn't want to use them in my case, because I want to get a better understanding of how things work in Async calls.

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems to me you understand the callback pattern well. Your problem might be more on the "flow control" of the callback responses: you need the responses to be aggregated sequentially, yet your server gives no guarantee that responses will be given back to you as such. You may try to build such flow control yourself as a learning exercise, or use a library that does it already. Alternatively, you can examine the source of Async to understand how flow control is handled there.